# Only show duplicate records - Oracle Sql

Tags: sql, oracle

The following query is constructed to give me all records where the source equals MLP. In some instances there may be two or more records per YPID. I only need to pull records where YPID is shown more than once and exclude all others. How can I accomplish this using my query below?

Here's my query:

```
select
mr.ypid,
mr.source_record_id,
mr.business_name,
mr.street_address,
mr.city,
mr.state,
mr.zip5
from MDM2.records mr 
join redirects r on r.source_record_id = mr.source_record_id
where mr.source_code = 'MLP'
and mr.status = 'A'
and mr.listing_advertiser_ind = 'A'
and r.is_ad = '1'
and r.source_customer_id is not null
and r.deleted = '0'
order by mr.ypid;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get duplicate records with cte and further join with your query to get only data for these values

```
with cte
as
(
SELECT mr.ypid
FROM MDM2.records mr
where mr.source_code = 'MLP'
and mr.status = 'A'
and mr.listing_advertiser_ind = 'A'
group by mr.ypid
having count(*) >1
)
select
mr.ypid,
mr.source_record_id,
mr.business_name,
mr.street_address,
mr.city,
mr.state,
mr.zip5
from MDM2.records mr 
join cte on 
mr.ypid = cte.ypid
join redirects r on r.source_record_id = mr.source_record_id
where  r.is_ad = '1'
and r.source_customer_id is not null
and r.deleted = '0'
order by mr.ypid;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you, RADAR

Answer (score 1):

try this
    select
    mr.ypid,
    mr.source_record_id,
    mr.business_name,
    mr.street_address,
    mr.city,
    mr.state,
    mr.zip5
    from MDM2.records mr,
         redirects r ,
         (select mr2.ypid,count(*) cnt 
          from MDM2.records mr2, 
          redirects r2 
          where r2.source_record_id = mr2.source_record_id
          and mr2.source_code = 'MLP'
          and mr2.status = 'A'
          and mr2.listing_advertiser_ind = 'A'
          and r2.is_ad = '1'
          and r2.source_customer_id is not null
          and r2.deleted = '0'
          group by mr2.ypid
          having count(*) > 1) as dups
    where r.source_record_id = mr.source_record_id
    and mr.source_code = 'MLP'
    and mr.status = 'A'
    and mr.listing_advertiser_ind = 'A'
    and r.is_ad = '1'
    and r.source_customer_id is not null
    and r.deleted = '0'
    and dups.ypid = mr.ypid
    order by mr.ypid;

Note: I changed the joining style to make it look clearer.
The idea is to make a virtual table "dups" that only has ypid's that are duplicates